# What does this bash script means

Tags: bash, shell

I've found the following line of code in a script. Could someone explain me what does this following line of code means?

Basically, the purpose of this line is find a set of files to archive. Since I am not familiar with bash scripts, it is difficult for me to understand this line of code.

```
_filelist=`cd ${_path}; find . -type f -mtime ${ARCHIVE_DELAY} -name "${_filename}" -not -name "${_ignore_filename}" -not -name "${_ignore_filename2}"`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's break it down:

`cd ${_path}` : changes to the directory stored in the `${_path}` variable

`find` is used to find files based on the following criteria:

- `.` : look in the current directory and recurse through all
  sub-directories
- `-type f`: look for regular files only (not directories)
- `-mtime ${ARCHIVE_DELAY}` : look for files last modified
  `${ARCHIVE_DELAY}*24` hours ago
- `-name "${_filename}"`: look for files which have name matching `${_filename}`
- `-not -name "${_ignore_filename}"` : do not find files which have
  name matching `${_ignore_filename}`
- `-not -name "${_ignore_filename2}"` : do not find files which have
  name matching `${_ignore_filename2}`

All the files found are stored in a variable called `_filelist`.

Answer (score 4):

The backtick (`) symbol assigns to the variable the output of the command.
Your script is assigning to $_filelist what you get by:

1. Changing directory to $_path
2. Finding in the current directory (.) files (-type f) where

   1. Name is $_filename (a pattern, I suppose)
   2. Name is not $_ignore_filename or $_ignore_filename2

I think you could as well change that to `find ${_path} ...` without the cd, but please try it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
_filelist=`somecode`
```

makes the variable _filelist contain the **output** of the command somecode.

Somecode, in this case, is mostly a find command, which searches recursively for files.

```
find . -type f -mtime ${ARCHIVE_DELAY} -name "${_filename}" -not -name "${_ignore_filename}" -not -name "${_ignore_filename2}"

find .
```

searches the current dir, but this was just before changed to be _path.

```
-type f
```

only searches in ordinary files (not dirs, sockets, ...)

```
-mtime
```

specifies the modification time of that files, to be the same as ${ARCHIVE_DELAY}

```
-name explains
```

itself, has to be "${_filename}"

```
-not name
```

explains itself too, I guess.

So the whole part sets the variable filelist to files, found by some criterias: name, age, and type.